# uploading image with php unable to move error write permissions and user permission are correct

Tags: javascript, php, linux, apache

Hello I have a little script that uploads an image with ajax, im my httpd error log im getting the following error:

```
[Fri Dec 11 01:04:23 2015] [error] [client 198.179.137.231] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpBvMSXh' to '/var/www/html/images/user_images/12241438_729936823776897_6949919207874282255_n.jpg' in /var/www/html/upload_image.php on line 4, referer: http://52.35.215.63/profile.php
```

I have set the images/user_images permissions to 666 and user apache because thats the user httpd is running under.

```
[root@ip-172-31-23-199 images]# ls -la
total 12
drw-rw-rw- 3 apache apache 4096 Dec 11 00:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 apache apache 4096 Dec 11 01:00 ..
drw-rw-rw- 2 apache apache 4096 Dec 11 00:41 user_images
[root@ip-172-31-23-199 images]#
```

upload_image.php

```
<?php
$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];   // Storing source path of the file in a variable
$targetPath = "/var/www/html/images/user_images/".$_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;    // Moving Uploaded file
?>
```

the form profile.php

```
            <form id="uploadimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="image_preview"><img id="previewing" src="" /></div>
                <div id="selectImage">
                <label>Select Your Image</label><br/>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required />
                <input type='hidden' name='file_name' id='user_name'>
                <button onclick="uploadImage();">upload</button>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

the js profile.php

```
  function uploadImage(){
    var user_name = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    document.getElementById("user_name").value = user_name;
    var form = document.getElementById('uploadimage');
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload_image.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: formData, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: One problem is that you have `move_uploaded_file()` being executed in your script even before you've uploaded the file.... you need to test if the form has been submitted in your code, and only execute the move if the form has been submitted

Comment: These are seperate scripts I guess I should've been more specific. Do you not see the error code I posted? It shows the exact error which shows the image is being uploaded because its the correct image name. @MarkBaker